# Using Laravel behind a load balancer

Tags: php, session, laravel, load-balancing

I have been working on a Laravel 4 site for awhile now and the company just put it behind a load balancer. Now when I try to login it basically just refreshes the page. I tried using fideloper's proxy package at https://github.com/fideloper/proxy but see no change. I even opened it up to allow all IP addresses by doing proxies => '*'. I need some help with knowing what needs to be done to get Laravel to work behind a load balancer, especially with sessions. Please note that I am using the database Laravel session driver.

The load balancer is a KEMP LM-3600.

Comment: which load balancer? there are many

Comment: I'm checking with the network guys and will update as soon as I know.

Comment: They have a KEMP LM-3600.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you to everyone for the useful information you provided. After further testing I found that the reason this wasn't working is because we are forcing https through the load balancer, but allowing http when not going through the load balancer. The login form was actually posting to http instead of https. This allowed the form to post but the session data never made it back to the client. Changing the form to post to https fixed this issue.

Comment: I don't know if this is an update as of Laravel 4.1, but setting up Trusted Proxies should now work. Laravel should properly create redirects and URLs properly. Was that form submit URL hard-coded to "http" ? I've tested laravel 4.1 behind a load-balancing proxy, and it functions correctly *when the trusted proxy is correctly set*.

Answer (score 0):

We use a load balancer where I work and I ran into similiar problems with accessing cPanel dashboards where the page would just reload every time I tried accessing a section and log me off as my IP address was changing to them. The solution was to find which port cPanel was using and configure the load balancer to bind that port to one WAN. Sorry, I am not familiar with laravel and if it just using port 80 then this might not be a solution.

Comment: We are using https so the load balancer is accepting connections on 443. How did you find out which port cPanel was using?

Comment: @Dalyn http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel " cPanel is commonly accessed on port 2082"

Comment: @Dalyn I have not looked at the KEMP LM-3600, but I know that with ours you can bind devices by MAC address on the internal network. If your site is the only one on your server and it is not on a different subnet than the balancer, then you may be able to ask the "network guys" to bind your server to one WAN and work away as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the session handling in Laravel 4 uses [Symfony 2 code, which lacks proper session locking](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4976) in all self-coded handlers that do not use the PHP provided session save handlers like "files", "memcached" etc.

This will create errors when used in a web application with parallel requests like Ajax, but this should occur unrelated to any load balancer.

You really should do some more investigation. HTTP load balancers do have some impact on the information flow, but the only effect on a PHP application would be that a single user surfing the site will randomly send the requests to any one of the connected servers, and not always to the same.

Do you also use any fancy database setup, like master-slave replication? This would affect sessions more likely, if the writing is only done on the master, the reading is done only on a slave, and this slave is behind the master with updating the last write operation. Such a configuration is not recommended as a session storage. I'd rather use Memcached instead. The PHP session save handler does implement proper locking as well...

Using fideloper's proxy does not make sense. A load balancer should be transparent to the web server, i.e. it should not act as a reverse proxy unless configured to do so.

Comment: I have switched the Laravel 4 session driver back to native. Are you saying that AJAX requests are going to be a problem unless I use the native session driver? The problem we are seeing is when I click on login it basically just posts to the page. I don't even get an error saying I didn't fill in the login fields. The site works fine when it doesn't go through the load balancer. We also get a connection interrupted message in the browser every 1-10 page loads. There is nothing fancy on the database. Windows Server 2008 running IIS and SQL Server with PHP configured and running with IIS.

Comment: Well, a native file based session will not work in a load balanced environment unless you make the load balancer sticky based on the session cookie. If the session switches between machines, the file with the session data does not.

Answer (score 0):

Use a shared resource to store the session data. File and memcached will surely not work. DB should be OK. That's what I'm using on a load balanced setup with a common database.

Comment: Did you have to do any additional configuration on the load balancer to get this to work? Are you using Laravel with your setup?

Comment: Yes, using Laravel. Both web heads access a common database which is where the session data is stored. The only significant configuration point is using the database session driver.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [TrustedProxy](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy) for a while now and its working fine.

the main issue with load balancers is proxy routing. the next is from the readme file and its what I was looking for.

> If your site sits behind a load balancer, gateway cache or other
>   "reverse proxy", each web request has the potential to appear to
>   always come from that proxy, rather than the client actually making
>   requests on your site.
>
> To fix that, this package allows you to take advantage of Symfony's
>   knowledge of proxies. See below for more explanation on the topic of
>   "trusted proxies".